# Spring data rest how to serve hal+json serialization for content-type json

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

We are using spring-data-rest to expose our repositories.
Choosing as default type `application/hal+json` produce the desired presentation of the resources and links, with content exposed as `_embedded` and links as `_links`.

Unfortunately, Firefox is not able to render `application/hal+json`, suggesting user to download the `hal+json` document if the user is navigating the api using the browser.
As a possible solution to this, we would like to support `application/json` as `defaultMediaType` and also hal+json if the user is explicitly requiring that.

Using `application/json` as `defaultMediaType` with spring-data-rest tough bypass the hal+json serialization provided by spring-hateoas, so the resources are displayed with "content" and "links".

I've tried to extends the `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter`, overriding the `configureHttpMessageConverter` this way

```
@Override
public void configureHttpMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter halConverter = new TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(ResourceSupport.class);
    halConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
    halConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaTypes.HAL_JSON));

    //make sure this is inserted first
    messageConverters.add(0, halConverter);
    super.configureHttpMessageConverters(messageConverters);
}
```

but the converter is not used to render the resources.

Any one has any suggestion on how to tackle this?

Comment: What do you mean Firefox is not able to render application/hal+json? I set network.http.accept.default to text/html,application/json,application/xhtml+xml,application‌​/xml;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.7 and can render hal+json just fine (meaning it looks like what is described in https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08).

Comment: Thank you Marc, but this require user to change settings on firefox and this is something we don't want to do. 
We would like to serve json as preferred media type for spring-data-rest, with the correct serialization of hal+json.
Interestingly, having default media type set to application/hal+json and requesting application/json (with header Accept:application/json) is making things working properly, but if we use default media type application/json, serialization is not the hal+json that we want to see

Comment: Good to know. By the way, instead of tweaking the about:config page, one could also install plugin such as [JSONView](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/jsonview/), which adds syntax highlighting to JSON rendering.

Comment: Yes, we thought about that too but as a possible solution but that would still require user to install a plugin. We would like to avoid that